# How do I work with POSIX paths in JXA

Tags: javascript-automation

In AppleScript I often need to convert between files as POSIX paths and as AppleScript’s native file aliases.

The way to do it is via the POSIX File class in standard additions:

```
set aFile to POSIX file "/"
get aFile's POSIX path
```

How do I do these casts/conversions in JXA? I’ve tried

```
var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

app.POSIXFile().make('/');
```

But I only get

> Error on line 4: Error: POSIXFile is not a valid class for application «Appname»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is right in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW31):

Use `Path`:

```
var file = Path('/');
```

And then you can use `file` anywhere file references would be allowed in AppleScript.

Though I still don’t know what happened to the `POSIXFile` type from the standard additions (or how I’d need to call it).